# Discrete Mathematics, Rosen, vs Mathematical Analysis of Thought by Boole

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

This is only partly a question - when I started with Discrete Math textbook by Ken Rosen, it opened by defining Propositions - examples included The Capital of Canada is Toronto.

When I started reading about conjunctions and disjunctions, I was confused - I did not understand why they existed.

For example, a conjunction is defined as a proposition that is true when both its constituents are true; and false otherwise. A truth table was also given illustrating this.
Given the examples in the textbook, I did not understand if:

- the conjunction operation itself resulted in the resultant compound proposition being true or false; or
- if the resultant compound proposition's truth table (in reality) resulted in us defining the operation as a conjunction.

The book did not help much in understanding this, since the propositions it gave did not seem to have any relation with each other.

I wanted to understand this better, and I had the Mathematical Analysis of Thought book by George Boole. I read the first chapter this morning, and it arrives at propositions in a very different way.

Boole describes all the reasoning process of a human, as simply classifications of objects into different classes.

So if you have items belonging to a Universe; X and Y are objects of two different types in that Universe; x and y are operations that select objects of type X and Y from this Universe;

- then xy is the act of first selecting objects of type Y from the Universe; and then selecting x elements from the result of the first act. We can understand this as an intersection of two sets, X and Y.
- x+y is the act of selecting x from the Universe; and then also selecting y from the Universe. This is the union of two sets, X and Y

Thus, for Boole, x and y are classification operations, that are abstract forms of reasoning by the brain.

From this point of view, a Proposition is something like saying object a is of Type A. It is the act of classification. A conjunction or a disjunction seem to be, thus, acts of classification which are a combination of other such acts executed in sequence. In Boole's view, he is modeling the brain's reasoning with this approach.

It appears this approach makes as much sense as starting with "A Proposition is a statement that is true or false", no? Or am I misunderstanding propositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what your question is but I think your confusion is natural. One thing that I think introductions to propositional logic don't really emphasize is that in practice the propositions we care about have [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) and these variables are important for understanding what is going on semantically.

For simplicity, let's consider propositions with a single free variable $x$ whose [domain of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse) is the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. An example of such a proposition is $x > 3$; this proposition is true for some integers (e.g. $x = 4$) and false for others (e.g. $x = 2$), and defines a function $\mathbb{Z} \to \{ T, F \}$ from the set of integers to the set of truth values. This function can in turn be identified with the subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ for which it returns the value $T$; in other words, semantically we can identify the "meaning" of a proposition with one free variable with the subset of the domain of discourse on which that proposition is true.

From this point of view,

- the conjunction of two propositions takes the intersection of their truth subsets; for example $x > 3 \text{ and } x < 10$ takes the intersection of the set $\{ 4, 5, 6, \dots \}$ with the set $\{ 9, 8, 7, \dots \}$ and produces the set $\{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \}$.
- the disjunction of two propositions takes the union of their truth subsets; for example $x = 3 \text { or } x = 10$ takes the union of the set $\{ 3 \}$ and the set $\{ 10 \}$ and produces the set $\{ 3, 10 \}$.

The significance of truth tables from this point of view is that they tell you how to take the conjunction or disjunction of two propositions if you think of them in terms of the functions $\mathbb{Z} \to \{ T, F \}$ they define. So, understanding this point of view requires learning how to switch between three different perspectives on what a proposition is:

1. A proposition is a statement about an object or objects in the domain of discourse.
2. A proposition is a (certain kind of) function from the domain of discourse to $\{ T, F \}$.
3. A proposition is a (certain kind of) subset of the domain of discourse.

Once you get used to propositional logic this sort of switching will become second nature, but it's often poorly explained and can be confusing in the beginning. From here we can generalize to more than one free variable; for example the proposition $x < y$ has two free variables and defines a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, namely the set of pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $x < y$.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I initially understood propositions the way you mention - A "proposition is a (certain kind of) subset of the domain of discourse.". Without the free variable, it is hard to understand. For example, I understood the proposition "Today is Friday" to be applied on a "Universe" of days. In this universe, the Proposition "Today is Friday" picks a set which is the set of Fridays. In the Rosen textbook, however, propositions with such variables are called Propositional Functions. Is that your understanding also? I will mark your answer as selected.

Comment: @ramiahariya: yes, the second perspective is (probably) what "propositional function" means here. But again one can switch freely between this and the third perspective. The operation going from 3 to 2 is called taking the indicator function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function